# "Regra" horizontal no ícone do <hr> e na página de help de edição

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, central-de-ajuda

### Melhor seria "Régua" horizontal

"Regra" é tradução literal de "Rule", sem contexto.

[image: Printscreen do erro]

**O Erro permanece, e no [help de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) também:**

> Regras horizontais
>
> Insira uma regra horizontal`<hr/>` colocando três ou mais hífens,
>   asteriscos ou sublinhados independentes em uma linha:

Reparem que também falta um espaço entre "horizontal" e o `<hr/>`.

**Update: achei melhor ainda, como sugerido pelo Gabe, "Linha" horizontal.**

Comment: Eu prefiro "linha horizontal". Alguém se importa?

Comment: @Gabe acho até melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feito! Como de costume, vai pro ar no próximo build.